# Where did my kids profile data go on the switch?

Tags: nintendo-switch

So we signed up online for Nintendo services, kids playing minecraft plus array of other games.   Now their accounts say to "Sign in with Nintendo Account" and there is no associated data.   If we sign in it says the account is already linked and get an error.   I obviously don't understand Nintendo account management so what am I doing wrong here?

To add on when we set up the accounts a while back we set the kids up with kid accounts under our parent account.   After going on nintendo's website we didn't see their accounts associated but had to pay 50 cents per account to associate them.   I am not really sure what to check or next steps since I don't want to mess up any saved data that still might be there.

Comment: Your best bet would be to straight up contact support. Doubt there's much any of us can do but have a look [here](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/16031/~/nintendo-account-was-deleted-or-deactivated). Are your children under 13? Nintendo is pretty strict when it comes to online features and children under the 13. Also, check [this](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/27046/p/897)

Comment: Someone may have cleared the cache (System->Formatting Options->Reset Cache)